# Icons and arrows in all tree columns

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm working on a tree in Extjs 6 with 3 columns, but I'm getting icons and arrows in all columns. It doesn't look like this [example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/tree/locking-treegrid.html).

I know that I could hide them with CSS, but they shouldn't be there. What am I doing wrong?

[This is how my tree looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNKB2.png)

**View**

```
Ext.define('CONVENIO.view.tipocontrato.TipoContrato', {
extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
//requires : [ 'CONVENIO.controller.TipoContrato', ],

//controller : 'tipocontrato',
store : Ext.create('CONVENIO.store.TipoContrato'),
xtype : 'tipo-contrato-tree',

useArrows : true,
rootVisible : false,
reserveScrollbar : true,
multiSelect: true,

columns : [ {
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    text : 'Tipo de Contratos',
    cellWrap : true,
    flex : 3,
    dataIndex : 'nombre',
    sortable  : true
}, {
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    text : 'Inicio',
    cellWrap : true,
    flex : 1,
    dataIndex : 'feInicio',
    sortable  : true
}, {
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    text : 'Fin',
    cellWrap : true,
    flex : 1,
    dataIndex : 'feFin',
    sortable  : true
} ],
bbar : [ '->', {
    xtype : 'componente-error'
}, {
    xtype : 'boton-nuevo',
}, {
    xtype : 'boton-editar',
}, '-', {
    xtype : 'boton-salir',
} ],
defaultButton : 'botonPrincipal',

/*listeners : {
    beforeitemexpand : 'onBeforeItemExpand',
    beforerender : 'onBeforeRender',
}*/

});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('CONVENIO.store.TipoContrato', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',   
model:  'CONVENIO.model.TipoContrato',

proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
    },
},

root : {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        {
            nombre: 'A',
            feInicio : '01/11/2015',
            feFin: '30/11/2015'
        },
        {
            nombre: 'B',
            feInicio : '01/11/2015',
            feFin: '30/11/2015',
            children:[{
                nombre: 'B.1',
                feInicio : '01/11/2015',
                feFin: '30/11/2015',
            }]
        },
        {
            nombre: 'C',
            feInicio : '10/11/2015',
            feFin: '30/11/2015',
        }
    ]
},

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first column should be a `treecolumn`. Remove the `xtype` for the others and just let it default.